# How does TS type intersection narrow down types?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a `queryObject` that I can build using TS mapped types along with utility type `Uncapitalize` like this:

```
type Params = {
  ParamOne: string;
  ParamTwo: string;
};

type Query<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: `&${Uncapitalize<K>}=`;
};

const queryObject: Query<Params> = {
  ParamOne: '&paramOne=',
  ParamTwo: '&paramTwo=',
};
```

Of course TS won't let me use `Uncapitalize` on any generic type `T`, so I can do type narrowing using `extends` to check if the type is `string` like so:

```
type Query<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? `&${Uncapitalize<K>}=` : never;
};
```

It works fine, but recently I came across an alternative which I can't quite understand

```
type Query<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: `&${Uncapitalize<K & string>}=`;
};
```

I don't get how type intersection narrows `K` type in that case, I've run some tests and it seems to work exactly like `extends` version.

**Question:**
How does it work? Shouldn't intersection only be used for combining several records properties? Is there an official explanation for this (I couldn't find one)? Any caveats for this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret every type as some mathematical set.
An intersection in the sets is a set of common elements
Union is the combination of all elements of two sets (A's elements that are not in B, the intersection of A and B, and B's elements that are not in A).

Any intersection with an empty set gives the empty set as a result. In the typescript empty set is `never`. Thus, the following intersections will result in `never`:

```
type Case1 = string & never // never
type Case2 = string[] & never // never
type Case3 = Record<string, unknown> & never // never
```

In the opposite union with `never` will result in the other set:

```
type Case1 = string | never // string
type Case2 = string[] | never // string[]
type Case3 = Record<string, unknown> | never // Record<string, unknown>
```

Any string literal is a subset of `string`, thus the intersection with `string` would result in the string literal itself, but with the union, it would result in just a string:

```
type Case1 = "literal" | string // string
type Case2 = "literal" & string // "literal"
```

Since, objects keys have the type of `PropertyKey`, which is `string | number | symbol`, `keyof Type` return this type, and  if you need to extract only string keys you have two ways of doing it:

```
{[K in Extract<keyof Type, string>]: {}}
```

or

```
{[K in keyof Type & string]: {}}
```

Example of the second case:

```
type K = 'str' | 1 | number | '2';
type OnlyStringKeys = K & string // 'str' | '2'
```

Since there is no intersection between `1`, `number`, and `string` they will result in an empty set (`never`).

In the context of intersecting two objects, it's a bit different and it is intentional behavior by the Typescript. The reason why it happens is that the compiler is unable to simplify the types, as it can do with primitive types, such as strings. Intersecting two objects result in their mathematical union.

For more example and explanations you can refer to this [blog](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2023/01/23/typescript-sets/)